# Необходимо проверить может ли пара ферзей напасть друг на друга

Tags: python, алгоритм, шахматы

Сначала мы с клавиатуры вводим число пар координат, потом вводим сами координаты и по этим координатам выставляем ферзей на шахматной доске.
Задача в том, что если ферзь может бить другую, то возвращаем "YES", если нет "NO.
У меня проблема с тем, что не получается проверка на "атаку" по диагонали.
Нужна помощь или совет!

Вот мой ход мыслей (без инпутов):

```
arr = [
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]


# for good vision
def show_arr(arr):
    for row in arr:
        print(''.join([f'{el:^4}' for el in row]))


#  placing our Queens by coordinates
def get_figure(arr, coords_list):
    for cord in coords_list:
        for ir, row in enumerate(range(8), start=1):
            for ic, col in enumerate(range(8), start=1):
                if ir == cord[0] and ic == cord[1]:
                    arr[row][col] = 'Q'
    return arr


def check(arr):
    s = 1
    for row in range(8):
        for col in range(8):
            if arr[row][col] == 'Q':
                if arr[row-s][col+s] == 'Q':
                    return 'YES'
                elif arr[row-s][col-s] == 'Q':
                    return 'YES'
                elif arr[row+s][col-s] == 'Q':
                    return 'YES'
                elif arr[row+s][col+s] == 'Q':
                    return 'YES'
                    s += 1
                    print(s)
    return 'NO'
        

if __name__ == '__main__':


    coords_list = [[1, 1], [3, 5], [7, 7]]

    show_arr(get_figure(arr, coords_list))

    print(check(get_figure(arr, coords_list)))
```

Comment: Сколько всего ферзей? В заголовке написано _"пара"_, но в коде 3. Не до конца понимаю задачу.

Comment: Допустим, ферзей может быть произвольное количество, тогда нужно вывести `YES`, если они все могут бить друг друга?

Comment: @nomnoms12 сначала мы вводим с клавиатуры цифру - коль-во ферзей, потом вводим координаты для этих ферзей.
Нет, достаточно, чтобы 1 из ферзей била другую.

Comment: @method, циклы с `enumerate` не хороши. Подумайте, надо ли пробегать все поля, чтобы в одном известном месте поставить ферзя?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy , согласен, это не обязательно, но оно хотя бы работает в отличии от проверки на "атаку".

Comment: @method, следите за моей мыслью. В циклах оказывается что `ir == row + 1` и `iс == col + 1`. Сделаем замену в условном операторе: `if row + 1 == cord[0] and col + 1 == cord[1]:`. Преобразуем в `if row == cord[0] - 1 and col == cord[1] - 1:`. Тогда в теле условного оператора можно заменить присваивание на `arr[cord[1] - 1][cord[0] - 1] = 'Q'`. Теперь можно убрать оба цикла и условие оставив только последнюю строку.

Answer (score 4):

Достаточно проверить условие:

```py
x1 - y1 == x2 - y2 or x1 + y1 == x2 + y2 or x1 == x2 or y1 == y2
```

Его несложно получить, если построить таблицу арифметических операций над координатами:

[image: Операции над координатами]
<sub>Источник фото: [stepik](https://stepik.org/lesson/13022/step/11?discussion=1106778&thread=solutions&unit=4363)</sub>

Для клеток, лежащих на диагоналях матрицы параллельных *главной*, **разности координат равны**. А для клеток, лежащих на диагоналях матрицы параллельных *вспомогательной*, **суммы координат равны**.

Comment: Спасибо, но в том то и дело, что у меня не получается реализовать это в моем цикле.

Comment: @method, не надо расставлять ферзей на поле чтобы проверить бьют ли они друг друга. Достаточно работать с координатами.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да, но в конечно итоге я хотел это сделать в GUI (Pygame или Tkinter)

Comment: Ферзи могут бить друг друга в трех случаях: на одной горизонтали, на одной вертикали, на одной диагонали. Если координаты ферзя обозначить (x,y) тогда получаем условие: `(x1 == x2) || (y1 == y2) || (abs(x1 -x2) == abs (y1 - y2))`